# What kind of expansion is $\sqrt{1+u} = 1+ \frac12u + \frac18u^2+\dotso$.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

What kind of expansion  is this $$ \sqrt{1+u} = 1+ \frac12u - \frac18u^2+\dotso$$

Where the 8 came from ?

Thank you

Comment: It is the taylor expansion (more concrete the Mac-Laurin-expansion) of $\sqrt{u+1}$

Comment: in that case it should $$ 1/2! .. 1/3! $$  now $$3!$$ is six not eight.

Comment: @monk See [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: Consider that you do not only have the inverses of the factorials. They have to be multiplied with the values of the derivates at the given point. Only very special functions (like $\exp(x),\sin(x),\cos(x)$ actually produce only inverses of factorials.

Comment: You might be interested in the sequence $1,1,2,5,14,42,132,429,1430,\dots$ appearing in the  value $(1-\sqrt{0.99996})/2=1.0000100002000050001400042001320042901430\dots$

Answer (score 2):

We know that

$$(1+x)^a=1+ax+\frac {a (a-1)}{2}x^2+\frac {a (a-1)(a-2)}{3!}x^3+.... $$

if $a=\frac {1}{2} $,  the third  term gives $\frac {-1}{8} x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(u)=\sqrt{1+u}$ is an analytic function in a neighbourhood of the origin and a solution of $f(0)=1$, $f(u)=2(1+u)\,f'(u)$. In particular, by assuming 
$$ f(u) = 1+\sum_{n\geq 1} c_n u^n \tag{A}$$
for any $u$ sufficiently close to the origin, we have
$$ 2(1+u)f'(u)=2(1+u)\sum_{n\geq 1}n c_n u^{n-1} = \sum_{n\geq 1} 2n c_n (u^n+u^{n-1})\\=2c_1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(2nc_n+2(n+1)c_{n+1}\right)u^n\tag{B} $$ 
hence by comparing $(A)$ and $(B)$ we get $c_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and
$$ c_n = 2n c_n + 2(n+1) c_{n+1}, \qquad c_{n+1}=-\frac{2n-1}{2n+2}c_n\tag{C}$$
so $c_2=-\frac{1}{4}c_1 = -\frac{1}{8}$ and in general $c_n=\frac{(2n-1)!!\cdot(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)\cdot(2n)!!}$.

Answer (score 1):

With $f(u)=\sqrt{1+u}$, a term in the Taylor series of $f$ at $0$ is
$$\frac{u^2}{2!} f''(0) = \frac{u^2}{2} \left[\frac{d}{du} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+u}}\right]_{u=0} = - \frac{u^2}{8} \left[(1+u)^{-3/2}\right]_{u=0}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is a polynomial expansion:
$$\sqrt{1+x}=(1+x)^{1/2}=\color{blue}{a_0}+\color{red}{a_1}x+\color{green}{a_2}x^2+\color{magenta}{a_3}x^3+\cdots$$
Plug $x=0$ to find $a_0$: 
$$(1+0)^{1/2}=a_0+0+0+0+\cdots \Rightarrow \color{blue}{a_0=1}.$$

Take derivative of both sides and plug $x=0$ to find $a_1$: $$\frac12(1+0)^{-1/2}=a_1 \Rightarrow \color{red}{a_1=\frac12}.$$

Take derivative of both sides twice and plug $x=0$ to find $a_2$: 
$$-\frac14(1+0)^{-3/2}=2a_2 \Rightarrow \color{green}{a_2=-\frac18}.$$

Take derivative of both sides three times and plug $x=0$ to find $a_3$: 
$$\frac38(1+0)^{-5/2}=6a_3 \Rightarrow \color{magenta}{a_3=\frac{1}{16}}.$$